# Twython get followers count

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Is there an easy way to get the number of followers an account has without having to loop through cursors? I'm looking for a simple function call which will return to me just the number of followers the use with a given Twitter ID has.

Just looking for the physical number not access to anything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing was `.show_user(user_id=twitter_id)` which returns (among other things) the followers count via `['followers_count']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use get users/lookup [endopoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup) to query up to 100 of screen names or user ids, `followers_count` is included as well.

In twython it would be [`lookup_user`](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/endpoints.py#L410) api function.

> Returns fully-hydrated user objects for up to 100 users per request, as specified by comma-separated values passed to the user_id and/or screen_name parameters.